# Dynamic content from JSON data with Jade, HTML5 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, html, node.js, pug

I'm getting a junk of JSON data and would like to work with that data without refreshing the site.

There are two divs:

- items
- item

If the user selects an item from the items list, div#item should be displayed instead of div#items with the item data. In Jade, I have to check if the item data has been defined:

```
- if(typeof(item) != 'undefined')
```

The click is handled by jQuery and I'm filling `item` with the corresponding data, hiding #items and showing #item, but due to the if-clause, Jade doesn't get that `item` now has a value.

I really would like to stick to the single request and do most of the data handling on the client-side as every refresh of the page automatically loads all the JSON data again. What would be the best solution for that?

Should I put the data into an HTML5 store?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what does Jade have to do with the JSON data, would like to help but don't understand the question..?

Comment: The problem is the 'if'. Without the 'if' I get ReferenceErrors, with it, I can't dynamically put data in the div as it doesn't get parsed from Jade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by just filling the div from jQuery with the .html() function. Anything better is highly appreciated.